# method call timer

Tags: c#, .net

How to call a method after the expiration of time

```
public void tMetro(string url)
          {
              tm.Stop();
              tm.Interval = 5000;
              tm.Start();
              method_8(url, "");
              if (wb.Url.AbsoluteUri == url)
                  wb.Stop();
          }
```

But not in the event Timer_tick

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tm.Stop();
            wb.Stop();
        }
```

Have tried through the `Thread.Sleep()` application freezes

Do not know how to be. Need your help

Comment: Try using RX reactive extension... http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples

Comment: The Tick _is_ the "expiration of time". Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: "Try using RX reactive extension"-

Can be an example to my case

    "The Tick is the "expiration of time". Or did I misunderstand you?"-

Yes it is This is convenient for one method, and I will be their lot.

Comment: Try posting more complete code: what is `tm`, where/when is it created etc. Which method should be called (method_8 ?) and why not in the Tick event?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way would be to call your function inside a [Timer Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx).

The Timer thread constructor has a variant that takes 4 parameters:

```
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback, // The function to be called
    Object state, // Any parameter passed to that function
    TimeSpan dueTime, // Delay before executing the function, this is what you want
    TimeSpan period // Set this to -1 if you want your function to be executed once.
)
```

Threading can be tough to cope with but it's the preferred method when it comes to consuming remote resources. This way You avoid freezing your main frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var thread = new Thread(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(5000); tm.Stop(); wb.Stop();
});
thread.Start();
```